# If statement without equality, what does that mean? (c)

Tags: c, if-statement

```
if(tree->left) 

if(!(*tree))
```

Do they mean:

```
 if(tree->left==0) 

 if((*tree)==1)
```

I did not find anything about this.

Comment: they means either null or zore

Comment: In C, a value of `0` evaluates as "false" when looked at in a logical expression. And a non-zero value is considered "true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means

```
if(tree->left != 0 ) 

if((*tree) == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In C there are not booleans but only integers. The if statement just check for equality with 0, evaluating 0 as false and everything else as true, so your examples are equivalent to

```
if(tree->left != 0) 

if((*tree)==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ will interpret `0` as `false` and anything else as `true`.

For example, doing

```
if (my_var & 0x0010) {
  printf("Hello world");
}
```

will print the message if `my_var` has the bit set in the fifth position.

Comment: It's somehow the other way round.

Comment: @el.pescado if you mean that `0` means true, no, you are wrong.

Comment: I mean, C (I'm not sure about C++) has no boolean type, thus it has no `true` and `false`. C99 introduced `<stdbool.h>` header, which defines `true` as `1` and `false` as `0` (at least on my Mac). So it's `false` defined as `0` rather than `0` defined as `false`. In practice, it doesn't matter much, though.